How to add a table to database within a custom plugin in WordPress
    $departments_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '" . $departments . "'(
        'ID' bigint(20) NOT NULL AND AUTO_INCREMENT,
        'name' varchar(128) NOT NULL,
        'parent' bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        'position' int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
        'description' varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY ('ID'),
        KEY 'parent' ('parent'))
        ENGINE=InnoDB" . $charset . ";";

make table with plugin in wordpress
but doesn't work

Hello.  Welcome to Stackoverflow.  This question needs more details so that someone can actually help you.  You should consider reading [ask] and [mre].  Include details as to HOW you are executing this code, what hooks are triggering this?
